# Known transformations of random variables that lead to a classical distribution?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I was wondering if there's a resource with a consolidated list of transformations, such that when applied to random variables, results in another random variable that is distributed according to some classical probability distribution?

I mean things along the lines of:

(1) A linear combination of independent normal random variables is a normally distributed random variable, and the joint distribution is multivariate normal

(2) Negative log of a uniform random variable is an exponentially distributed random variable

(3) Exponential of an exponentially distributed random variable is a uniformly distributed random variable

Comment: Would page three of [this document](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/2008amstat.pdf) be what you're looking for?

Comment: Many of the Wikipedia articles on probability distributions have a section on related distributions.  For example, [gamma distributions are listed as related to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Related_distributions) exponential distributions, chi-squared distributions, Erlang distributions, Poisson distributions,  Maxwell–Boltzmann distributions, generalized gamma distributions, inverse gamma distributions, beta distributions, normal distributions, Wishart distributions, negative binomial distributions, Tweedie distributions and no doubt more.